# Laravel Eloquent: Product, Attributes and Attribute Values Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I've a scenario for product and attributes relationship.

Models:

1. Product (table: **products**)
2. Attributes (table: **attributes**)
3. Attribute Values (table: **attribute_values**, foreign key: **attribute_id**)

A product can have multiple attributes so this will be easy with **many to many** relation b/w product and attributes

Model: **Attribute**

```
<?php

class Attribute extends Model{
    public function products()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Model: **Product**

```
class Product extends Model{
    public function attributes()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class);
    }
}
```

but, when assigning an attribute to an item **user** can opt out one of the attribute value from **attribute_values** i.e., the values assigned to an attribute.

how can I manage this in eloquent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would create a Pivot between products and attribute_values, and than you can use it the "Eloquent way" like this:

```
$products->sync(AttributeValues::where('attribute_id',$attribute_id);
```

and then if you want to detach a single attribute_value you can detach it using its instance

Comment: Thanks, I've restructured the schema same as you suggested.

Comment: HI @Shaheryar TVS can you please help i have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

[image]
I have designed a database schema, is that true ?

Comment: The table `ItemAttribute` does not need to be `value` column